# nginx: [emerg] getgrnam("nobody") failed

Tags: nginx, gcloud, lets-encrypt

while installing letsencrypt certificate the output error is:

```
nginx: the configuration file /jet/etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok 
nginx: [emerg] getgrnam(“nobody”) failed 
nginx: configuration file /jet/etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

but if I run:

```
nginx -t
```

to see if there are configuration errors in the nginx.conf file,
`nginx -t` return the output:

```
nginx: the configuration file /jet/etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /jet/etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Every now and then on WordPress I also get the error:

> internal server 500 error

and I don’t know if this is related to the problem I described above
My web server is (include version):

The operating system my web server runs on is (include version):

```
Linux lemp7-optimized-g2-1-vm 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u4 (2018-08-21) x86_64
```

[jeware lemp7 stack profile](http://jetware.io/appliances/jetware/lemp7_optimized_g2-170723)

## jetware

I managed to install the certificates by inserting a line with the “user nobody nogroup;” in the nginx.conf file

After the installation I removed the line with the “user nobody nogroup;” in the nginx.conf file

`sudo wget https://dl.eff.org/certbot-auto`

`sudo mv certbot-auto /jet/etc/letsencrypt/certbot-auto`

`sudo chown root /jet/etc/letsencrypt/certbot-auto`

`sudo chmod 0755 /jet/etc/letsencrypt/certbot-auto`

`sudo chmod a+x /jet/etc/letsencrypt/certbot-auto`

`sudo /jet/etc/letsencrypt/certbot-auto --nginx --nginx-ctl /jet/bin/nginx --nginx-server-root /jet/etc/nginx --config-dir /jet/etc/letsencrypt`

this produce this output:

`nginx: the configuration file /jet/etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: [emerg] getgrnam(“nobody”) failed
nginx: configuration file /jet/etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed`

but if I run:
`nginx -t`
to see if there are configuration errors in the nginx.conf file,
nginx -t return the output:

`nginx: the configuration file /jet/etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /jet/etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful`

every now and then on WordPress I also get the error: `internal server 500 error`
and I don’t know if this is related to the problem I described above

I will probably also have problems with automatic certificate renewal if I do not resolve this situation

Answer (score 1):

Well I have solved the problem. Fortunately I managed to find the error in the log and I understood what happened.

**“certbot-auto”** installs the certificates using the user: **nobody**. In my system there already existed by default a user “nobody” of the group “nogroup” but has no access to nginx. [user nobody](https://askubuntu.com/questions/329714/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-nobody-user)

So to be able to install the certificates I had to insert a line with the directive: user nobody nogroup; inside nginx.conf.

This allowed the installation of certificates. However, this procedure has changed the permissions in the directory: /jet/tmp/nginx/
where instead of: **my_ssh_user:my_ssh_group** I found: **nobody:my_ssh_group** and with this modified setting I received the **internal server 500 error** on the WordPress admin panel. So the problem is not related to WordPress but to the certificate installation procedure.

After installing the certificates I removed the **user nobody nogroup directive;** because during the restart of nginx, a warning came up saying that this directive is not supported and therefore will be ignored.

Restoring the permissions with **chmod** on the directory: **/jet/tmp/nginx** I **fixed** the problem and the **internal server 500 error** disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Here the [link](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/error-while-i-install-the-certificates-nginx-emerg-getgrnam-nobody-failed/92068) of the same discussion on letsencrypt. I still doubt that the error could recur when I have to renew the certificates.

A possible solution could be to assign the ssh user of the virtual instance that does not have root permissions, root permissions by adding it to the root group.

On virtual hosts, when an instance is launched, a user ssh is created.
This user, for security reasons, does not have root permissions.
Letsencrypt by default installs the certificates on the / etc / letsencrypt folder, which has root permissions (user: root group: root).

I had to install the certificates in the folder where the ssh user can have access (user: myssh_user group: myssh_group), ie su / jet / etc / letsencrypt

Could it be that the error was caused by this?